# which higher layer abstraction to use for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, skflow, tflearn

I am looking for higher layer abstractions for my deep learning project.

Few doubts lately.

1. I am really confused about which is more actively maintained [tflearn](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn)([docs](http://tflearn.org)), or [tensorflow.contrib.learn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn). But projects are different and actively contributed on Github. I did not find why are people working this way, same goal, same name, but working differently.
2. That was not enough, we also have [skflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow), why do we have this project separately, this aims to mimic scikit-learn like functionality for deep learning(just like **tflearn** do).
3. There are more and more coming, which one choose, and which one will be maintained in future?

Any ideas?

**PS**: I know this might get closed. but I would definitely want some answers first. Those wanting it closed, please care to drop a reason/hint/link in comments

Comment: FWIW, tf.contrib.learn is created by an joint effort of google-internal and open-source contributors. tflearn doesn't involve google.

Comment: This question isn't about a coding problem, but is about a resource search (picking docs to read) and library choice (skflow vs tflearn vs tensorflow). Both are specifically off topic as open ended discussions that would be better handled on some other blog, twitter, or discussion forum, not a Q&A site.

Comment: @scai, your comment is helpful, but it doesn't answer my question. Which is gonna be maintained longer and has better community etc? Are they doing the same things in both etc?

Comment: @MatthewMartin, thanks, for the reason

Comment: keras seems to be fairly popular. Also there's tf_slim. IMHO until TF API stabilizes (ie, version 1.0), none of the higher-level frameworks are going to be very mature/stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about keras (https://keras.io/)? It is easy to use. However you can do pretty much everything you want with it. It uses either theano or tensorflow as its backend. Kaggle contests are often solved using keras (e.g. https://github.com/EdwardTyantov/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation).

Edit:

Because you did not specify python I would also recommend matconvnet if you look for more abstraction.